# mod_ntlm for RHEL 5.3

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat, ntlm

I tried to compile mod_ntlm for Oracle HTTP Server but got all sorts of errors, can someone 
point me to a pre-compiled binary?

Tried everything at http://wiki.bestpractical.com/view/NtlmAuthentication still no go

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found this so much easier to install and work with:

http://search.cpan.org/~speeves/Apache2-AuthenNTLM-0.02/AuthenNTLM.pm

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. From a performance perspective, would a pre-compiled Apache module (.so) be faster than a Perl module?

Comment: Performance not an issue.  You don't want your web server flooding your domain controller with auth requests, so we applied the module only to one web page.  Our main include looks for a cookie that holds a GUID that's stored in a mysql sessions table, and if the GUID isn't present, it redirs users to the auth page, which is where the cookie is written and the sessions table populated (and redired back to requested page).  With 24 hour cookie, thousands of pages can get loaded with just one call to the auth page every 24 hours.